# How to mock/stub websocket requests leaving docker container

Tags: docker, websocket, proxy, docker-compose

I want to write e2e tests for a dockerized app, that uses websockets, so i need to mock all external requests. I have tried different kinds of proxy servers using the docker env variables

```
      HTTP_PROXY: http://nginx:8080
      HTTPS_PROXY: http://nginx:8080
      NO_PROXY: localhost,127.0.0.1
```

But no matter what i do, the websockets requests just go to it's original host and doesn't hit my proxy server.

Comment: What's your config ? Please, add at lease a docker-compose and dockerfiles

Comment: I just created a minimal reproducible example in this repo: https://github.com/rootkc/docker-nginx-mock-websockets where you can see that regular HTTP traffic gets proxied to my mock server just fine, but websockets doesn't. Thanks for your help!